# .vshost.exe file has different .Net framework version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.6.2

I'm trying to update some of our software to .Net 4.6.2 for TLS1.2 compliance ([eWAY for example](https://www.eway.com.au/tls-updates)).  When I run the application standalone it connects fine, but when I debug it via Visual Studio 2015 I get the error indicating I'm not using the correct TLS version (and hence .Net version).

I have ReSharper installed which included dotPeek, so I peeked and see that vshost is still using the 4.5 framework:
[image: framework version comparison]

I "cleaned" the solution, and forcibly deleted everything from the output directory (had to shut down VS to delete the .vshost.exe file).  Still the same behaviour.

Have I missed a setting somewhere?  I don't like the fact that when I debug I'm getting different behaviour to when I release the application.

Comment: Just disable it: Project > Properties > Debug tab > untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".  Nothing lost, it was removed completely in VS2017.

Comment: @HansPassant I could, but ["The hosting process is a feature in Visual Studio that improves debugging performance, enables partial trust debugging, and enables design time expression evaluation."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/hosting-process-vshost-exe)

Comment: So you have no idea what any of this means.  Then how do you know you need it?  You don't.

Comment: @HansPassant Hah, good call.  For the most part true.  But I understand it makes debugging launch faster.  Additionally there must be a way to debug _the same code_ that I'm going to deploy!  It's a matter of principle.  At this point I don't need to debug it any further, but I'd still like to know why the debugger doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: And are there any other instances where the debugger doesn't accurately reflect deployed code.  I've lost trust.